# Docker compose, running containers in net:host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

I want to spawn 3 services in the "host" net using docker-compose. Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    net: "host"
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    net: "host"
  app:
    image: tomcat
    net: "host"
```

I got the following error:

```
$ docker-compose up
[31mERROR[0m: Validation failed in file '.\docker-compose.yml', reason(s):
Unsupported config option for services.app: 'net'
Unsupported config option for services.mysql: 'net'
Unsupported config option for services.nginx: 'net'
```

I'm using boot2docker on windows.

Docker, and Docker-compose version:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.10.2, build c3959b1
$ docker-compose -version
docker-compose version 1.6.0, build cdb920a
```

If I run all services manually by using `docker run --net = "host"` everything is working fine.

In the documentation I read that **net** command is **supported in docker-compose**:

> **net**
>
> Networking mode. Use the same values as the docker client --net parameter.
>
> net: "bridge"
>
> net: "none"
>
> net: "container:[name or id]"
>
> net: "host"

https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/compose/yml/#net

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update based on @andy-shinn's answer, the parameter is called `network_mode: "host"`. As documented in [docker compose version 3 #network_mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode).

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Those documents are outdated. I'm guessing the 1.6 in the URL is for Docker 1.6, not Compose 1.6. Check out the correct syntax here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode. You are looking for `network_mode` when using the v2/v3 YAML format.

Comment: That's really confusing... I'll bookmark the documentation link right away.  network_mode is working fine thanks!

Comment: As I understood, I shoud use network_mode: "host"  under service?

Comment: note that `network_mode: host` won't work on docker for Mac

Comment: @FlavienVolken on mac, one solution is to use the host IP explicitly.  There is some special hostname you can use which points to this (docker_host_domain or something like that, i forget).

Answer (score 95):

Just print

`network_mode: "host"`

Comment: 'network_mode' and 'networks' cannot be combined.

In case you already have networks - it won't work.

Answer (score 68):

you can try just add

```
network_mode: "host"
```

example :

```
version: '2'
services:
  feedx:
    build: web
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:8000:8000"
    network_mode: "host"
```

list option available

```
network_mode: "bridge"
network_mode: "host"
network_mode: "none"
network_mode: "service:[service name]"
network_mode: "container:[container name/id]"
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode

Comment: is the port forwarding ignored in this case?

Comment: `docker-compose up` will fail with a message: docker.errors.InvalidArgument: "host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings. It is notable that running `docker-compose config` does not catch this as of version 3.8.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I am answering very late. But I was also having a problem configuring host network in docker compose. Then I read the documentation thoroughly and made the changes and it worked. Please note this configuration is for docker-compose version "3.7". Here einwohner_net and elk_net_net are my user-defined networks required for my application. I am using host net to get some system metrics.

Link To Documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#host-or-none

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    image: ramansharma/einwohnertomcat:v0.0.1
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      ports:
       - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
     - type: bind
       source: /proc
       target: /hostfs/proc
       read_only: true
     - type: bind
       source: /sys/fs/cgroup
       target: /hostfs/sys/fs/cgroup
       read_only: true
     - type: bind
       source: /
       target: /hostfs
       read_only: true
    networks:
     hostnet: {}
    networks:
     - einwohner_net
     - elk_elk_net
networks:
 einwohner_net:
 elk_elk_net:
   external: true
 hostnet:
   external: true
   name: host
```

Comment: > Only used if you use docker stack commands. If you use the docker-compose command, use network_mode instead.