# Docker Version 18.04.0-ce ignores unsupported options: network_mode

Tags: docker, shiny, docker-compose

For a small project, I want an application in a docker container to connect to the localhost of the machine. An answer to this question: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) tells me the preferred way is to use `--net="host"` in the docker run command.

I use a compose file to start the container. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960452/docker-compose-running-containers-in-nethost) told me the `net` option was renamed to `network_mode: "host"`.

Here is the beginning of the compose file

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  shiny:
    image: paulrougieux/eutradeflows
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "3838:3838"
```

When I start this file

```
 sudo docker stack deploy -c stackshiny.yml shiny
```

I get the error:

```
Ignoring unsupported options: network_mode
```

For information

```
$ sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:   18.04.0-ce
Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  18.04.0-ce
```

How do I enable connection to a database on the host from a docker container?

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the [docs for docker-compose file network_mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode):

> Notes
>   This option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a (version 3) Compose file.
>   network_mode: "host" cannot be mixed with links.

The `network_mode` cannot be used when deploying on docker swarm using `docker stack deploy`. This is not new with version 18.04 but is rather older.

The `network_mode` can only be used with docker-compose when deploying the container on the local machine using `docker-compose up`.

Comment: But I'm not deploying in a swarm mode, I just want to use this container on one server. I thought `docker stack deploy` had replaced `docker-compose` for all purposes.

Comment: @PaulRougieux `docker stack` is only for docker swarm. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/#extended-description

Comment: [This docker issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1031) may be related. OK I see the output of `sudo docker network ls`  tells me the scope is `swarm`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get around some of the limitations of the docker stack deploy by specifying the mode in the ports section:

for example in your docker-compose.yml file:

```
ports:
  # Bypass the routing mesh by setting mode to host
  - target: 8080
    published: 80
    protocol: tcp
    mode: host
```

This is covered in the section "Bypassing the routing mesh" here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/

And listed as an option in the docker compose-spec in the section "ports long syntax" here:
https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md